# Using jquery selectors on array containing cloned dom elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

How would one go about using jQuery selectors on an array of cloned dom elements:

Say I created the array like this:

```
var refDom = $(".items").clone(true, true);
```

Would it be possible to return some of the elements via selectors, or atleast get the array index?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, just do:

```
refDom.find('.somelement');
```

And to access the elements by index you can do:

```
refDom.eq(2).whatever();
```

Comment: Thanks, and to include the item itself, a method like this can be used: refDom.find('*').andSelf().filter(selector);

Answer (score 0):

You can use regular selectors:

```
refDom.find(".your-selector")
```